# MariaDb vs MySQL JSON_ARRAYAGG JSON_OBJECT Without Escaping

Tags: mysql, json, mariadb, json-arrayagg

I have a select query, which works just fine in my localhost MySQL database environment. It should return json object.

When I run the same query on my hosted public server with MariaDB 10.5.15 installed, the returned json includes several backslashes, escaping characters.

Here is the code:

```
        SELECT 
        json_object(
            'id', C1.Category1ID,
            'text', C1.Category1Name,
            'nodes', JSON_ARRAYAGG(
                JSON_OBJECT(
                    'id', C2.Category2ID, 
                    'text', C2.Category2Name, 
                    'nodes', C2.nodes, 
                    'class', 'nav-level-2', 
                    'href', 'admin-categories-2.php'
                )
            ),
            'class', 'nav-level-1',
            'href', 'admin-categories-1.php'
        ) AS JSON
    FROM categories_1 C1

        LEFT JOIN (
        
            SELECT 
                C2.Category1ID, 
                C2.Category2ID, 
                C2.Category2Name, 
                JSON_ARRAYAGG(
                    JSON_OBJECT(
                        'id', C3.Category3ID, 
                        'text', C3.Category3Name, 
                        'class', 'nav-level-3',
                        'href', 'admin-categories-3.php'
                    )
                ) as nodes
            FROM categories_2 C2
                LEFT JOIN categories_3 C3 ON C3.Category2ID = C2.Category2ID AND C3.Category3Status = 1 
            WHERE C2.Category2Status = 1 
            GROUP BY C2.Category2ID
            ORDER BY C2.Category2Order, C3.Category3Order  
            
        ) C2 ON C2.Category1ID = C1.Category1ID
        
    WHERE C1.Category1Status = 1 
    GROUP BY C1.Category1ID 
    ORDER BY C1.Category1Order 
    ;
```

My question is how to write this query correctly for MariaDB.

I am attaching result from MySQL (img1) and MariaDB (img2).

[image]
[image]

I am attaching create and insert statements for db here:

```
    CREATE TABLE `categories_1` (
  `Category1ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Category1Name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Category1Name_FR` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Category1Photo` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Category1Order` int(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Category1Status` int(1) DEFAULT 1,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Category1ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Top level category'

CREATE TABLE `categories_2` (
  `Category2ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Category2Name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Category2Name_FR` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Category2Order` int(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Category2Status` int(1) DEFAULT 1,
  `Category1ID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'To which parent level category it fits',
  PRIMARY KEY (`Category2ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=15 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Mid level category'

CREATE TABLE `categories_3` (
  `Category3ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Category3Name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Category3Name_FR` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Category3Order` int(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Category3Status` int(1) DEFAULT 1,
  `Category2ID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'To which parent level category it fits',
  PRIMARY KEY (`Category3ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=20 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Bottom level category'


INSERT INTO `categories_1` VALUES (1,'Meat','Meat-fr','meat.jpg',1,1),(2,'Fish & Sea Food',NULL,'fish.jpg',2,1),(3,'Fruit & Vegetables',NULL,'fruit-veg.jpg',3,1),(4,'Test L1',NULL,'categories-default.jpg',4,0);
INSERT INTO `categories_2` VALUES (1,'Beef','Feef-fr',1,1,1),(2,'Lamb',NULL,2,1,1),(3,'Pork',NULL,3,1,1),(4,'Veal',NULL,4,1,1),(5,'Poultry-Fowl',NULL,6,1,1),(6,'Sausages and Bacon',NULL,5,1,1),(7,'Salmon',NULL,8,1,2),(8,'Flat Fish',NULL,9,1,2),(9,'Common Fish',NULL,10,1,2),(10,'Squid family',NULL,11,1,2),(11,'Shellfish',NULL,12,1,2),(12,'Tuna',NULL,13,1,2),(13,'Other Fish',NULL,14,1,2),(14,'TEST L2',NULL,7,0,1);
INSERT INTO `categories_3` VALUES (1,'Specialist Beef','Specialist Beef-fr',1,1,1),(2,'Wagyu',NULL,2,1,1),(3,'Japanese Wagyu',NULL,3,1,1),(4,'Other Beef',NULL,4,1,1),(5,'All Lamb',NULL,6,1,2),(6,'All Pork',NULL,5,1,3),(7,'All Veal',NULL,7,1,4),(8,'All Poultry-Fowl',NULL,11,1,5),(9,'Pork Sausages',NULL,8,1,6),(10,'Other meats',NULL,9,1,6),(11,'Bacon',NULL,10,1,6),(12,'All Salmon',NULL,12,1,7),(13,'All Flat Fish',NULL,13,1,8),(14,'All Common Fish',NULL,14,1,9),(15,'All Squid family',NULL,15,1,10),(16,'All Shellfish',NULL,16,1,11),(17,'All Tuna',NULL,17,1,12),(18,'All Other Fish',NULL,18,1,13),(19,'TEST L3',NULL,999,0,14);
```

Comment: And how do I do that?

Comment: please edit your question to add (as text,  not images) output of `show create table categories_1;` and `show create table categories_2;` and insert statements to create the data demonstrating the problem?

Comment: Why are you developing with a different database than you use in production? You should always use the same brand and same version in both environments. This applies to database, language, framework, and all the other components of your technology stack.

Comment: Question updated with create and insert MySQL statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MariaDB have no JSON datatype (JSON keyword is an alias for LONGTEXT keyword only), it may treate string type value as JSON only.

You use construction `JSON_ARRAYAGG( JSON_OBJECT( ...`. In MariaDB the value produced by JSON_OBJECT is string ! It is **one solid string**, not complex value of JSON datatype. Hence during JSON_ARRAYAGG this solid string value which contains the chars needed in quoting is processed, and all doublequote chars are quoted.

See [FIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=10a96a458844a8ecf5b50628bd1d9447), especially last and pre-last code blocks. In pre-last block pay special attention to the doubequote chars which wraps the whole value (not inner doublequotes which are quoted by the slashes).

I do not see the way to fix this in MariaDB. There is no method to tell the function that the value provided as an argument is not string but JSON - there is no such datatype.

Wait until MariaDB implements JSON datatype (if) and upgrade.

Comment: What a great effort you did on this issue, setting up everything in db fiddle. I would have done it by myself, if I would know for it. Anyway, I have found somewhere yesterday, while googling the problem, that is is some kind of bug in MariaDB version 10.5 and that it is sold out in version 10.6. In the fiddle you have prepared, you can see that it rally works in version 10.6. So I will have to ask my hosting provider to upgrade to the latest version. Thank you very much for your help.